# Is CouchDB on Android needed for Users of App?

Tags: android, nosql, couchdb

Im Trying to use CouchDb as a NoSQL database and my main purpose is to create an application on android which use couchDB instead of sqlite! And I want to use this database locally , so with no server connection!

I have seen that you need to buy this on android market to use it! I'm wondering if I'm going to use this should all the users of my application by couchDB first in android market to be able to use my application?

or somehow it will be included? How does this thing work? Is there anyway that I can skip buying it and include this technology in my own application?

And please let me know if there is some other NoSQL that I can use on android!

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I want it the db be offline by the way!

Comment: Didn't see the offline clause in the comment. Removed my answer.

Comment: But Is it possible in total to do this locally with couchdb? can you give me something useful that I can go through it and use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to purchse it to use it, as it is an open source library covered by the Apache license.

Speaking of NoSQL I've successfully used both [NeoDatis](http://neodatis.wikidot.com/) and [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/android/) in the Android environment.  Both of these libraries are object databases and are surprisingly fast and easy to use.  In fact, the claim is that they are faster than ORM/Relation Databases.  I think they are a great fit for a low-user (1 user) low bandwidth environment.

Here's an example of db4o in Android:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-db4o-android-application

By the way, db4o is open source, but GPL, which makes it a difficult license to integrate into non-GPL products.  They also have a pay-license version.

Comment: Can this be used as offline databse?

Comment: I don't want to connect to a server? I want to have the database locally on the phone and read and write from it!

Comment: Oh, I understand.  Yes, you can use these databases purely on the phone with no internet connection or server required.

Comment: It's very slow for my amount of data! :(

Comment: How much data are you dealing with?

Comment: @KhashayarNapster You should move your data to a server. A cell phone is not supposed to manage 1 million rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-Android

This is an embeddable Java library that wraps SQLite, so it is fast, native, and lightweight.

It syncs with Apache CouchDB so it has the offline mode you want. It also has a REST/JSON api very similar to CouchDB.

Enjoy!

Comment: so is it basically sqlite? because i tried sqlite and it was really slow for me! and it was suggested to me to go for nosql instead