# Picking database for an Android app

Tags: android, sql, mongodb, database

I want to build a drinks app with my friend, just to play around with building Android applications and programming.

We'd like to include user login, meaning authentication. Data that would be persisted would include recipes for drinks, associated with comments, written reviews, numerical ratings, categories, etc.

My main question is what sort of database to use for this type of application?
I have experience with both SQL (MySQL and MSSQL) and MongoDB.
I was leaning towards Mongo - flexibility from lack of structured columns is appealing to me, however I have never done user authentication before - storing passwords as hash etc. 
If Mongo is appropriate, can anyone point me in the correct direction? I have googled before and remember there are some libraries for this.

Comment: The easiest way to do database + Android is to use SQLite since that is directly [supported](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) by Android. Using other databases is [not that easy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335947/is-couchdb-on-android-needed-for-users-of-app)

Comment: As @Anurag suggested, I think I will use a web service with database hosted remotely, then I can just call the api from Android.

Answer (score 0):

For persistent local storage you can only use SQLite in android. This SQLite storage is supported by android operating system using [these](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) classes.

If you are considering remote persistent storage then in that case any database hosted on a remote server can be used to store data.